# What was the meaning of the scene of Albedo at the end of Overlord season 2 episode 10

Tags: overlord

At the very end of Season 2, Episode 10 of Overlord, Albedo is spending time with her Ainz dolls, when Ainz orders her to prepare for a raid to save a human.

Most importantly, the camera panned over to where she was looking, a banner of what I believe is the Guild symbol torn off the wall and thrown on the ground, then a banner in the background behind her, and Albedo is showing disgust towards her orders. There seems to be a lot of emphasis on those banners, so what exactly was going on in that scene.

Comment: What about the same scene but the manga, where she saids " I want to meet Ainz-sama. I want to meet him." In the scenes she seems to be playing with a small child version of Lord Ainz ,so she is either saying she wants to meet the child that she bears with Ainz or that she knows Lord Ainz is not who he is pretending to be and wants to meet the real human behind the Lord Ainz charade.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Albedo is playing with the Ainz dolls when she's interrupted by Ainz, but she's happy that Ainz will be talking with her or giving her an order. But her mood suddenly changes when Ainz mentions that Tuare has been abducted, she's fast at reading the situation and knows that Ainz will be ordering her for preparations to save that girl.

She still does raise an objection whether there is any value in saving an *inferior* creatures such as a human. She's also shocked after hearing that Ainz promised Tuare (an inferior creature according to Albedo) protection under his great name. She accepts the order but we can see that she's unsatisfied and not happy about this.

> Still I don't understand, **Ainz Ooal Gown**. This is ridiculous.

It's probably about the fact that AOG was originally the name of the guild. So she probably just doesn't like the name, because it also refers to the other supreme beings that **abandoned** them. She hates that Momonga changed his name to that of the guild which abandoned him and all of Nazarick. She hates it because they not only abandoned the NPC's but they also left Momonga all alone (That's why the flag hung at the back is the Momonga's personal flag and the one trampled is that of AOG).

Ainz is incredibly lonely. It is just not showed that well in the anime

> Today is the last day Yggdrasil's servers will run. Why not stay until
>   the end - Momonga after Herehero-san logs out.

Albedo created an elite group in order to search for players in the new world, but it is also implied that she made the group so that she could kill the other supreme beings if they ever showed up (this follows up according to the @paul's answer above and makes sense)

Momonga loves his comrades dearly and knows their situation (about the server being shut down and their personal lives at stake). He knows that they didn't betray him but Albedo (being an NPC) is unable to comprehend it at all.

> No, that's not it. No one betrayed me. The guild weapon, Staff of Ainz
>   Ooal Gown. We played recklessly to make it. Some members used their
>   paid vacation and others fought with their wives to make time and get
>   the materials for this... That's right, everyone's livelihood was at stake.... It can't be helped that they all chose real life in the end

Comment: I didn't want to go into the Albedo's task force theory since it's still just speculation and HEAVY spoilers, but yeah, I agree with that theory as well.

Answer (score 13):

She's showing contempt over the Ainz Ooal Gown banner, and worshipping Momonga's personal banner. She was made to love Momonga through her settings, so she's not really happy with him dismissing that name. She wants him to be Momonga, not Ainz. Another factor of her discontent is the fact that the rest of the NPCs of Nazarick would obey their creators orders before Ainz' (she questions them about this), so aside from Pandora's Actor, she's the only other one that would place Ainz above any other of the 41 Supreme Beings. Ainz taking over that name was done to raise awareness of the name to lure any potential comrade that might have been transported to that world, a prospect that Albedo seems to not be too fond of since it would lower Ainz authority in her eyes.

Let's say for example Peroroncino ends up being in the new world and joins Nazarick. If he were to order something to Shalltear that would conflict with an order from Ainz, Shalltear would comply with Peroroncino's order. This is not acceptable for Albedo. Momonga's authority should be unshakable in her eyes.

Comment: The very last thing she says (at least in the translation I watched) is "This is ridiculous", I took it as she will turn on him eventually, because she doesn't agree with his ideology or rather his decisions to treat humans that highly. What's your opinion on that :?

Comment: @Deadzone check out the complete answer now

Comment: @paulnamida thanks for your answer, I have used it as a reference to my theory below.

Comment: @Deadzone Albedo would do anything, even kill herself if Ainz ordered so. Her contempt is against the guild itself, the other members that abandoned Nazarick.

Comment: @paulnamida I see it makes sense now, thanks for the elaboration! :)